# Best approach to get the data from the server while updating(Caching)

Tags: android, performance, caching, android-asynctask, android-service

Hi this is my first android app and please forgive if this question is very basic or already has been asked because i have not found an appropriate answer.

#### How Gmail and twitter (app) sync their data in background and what happens if users click too many times in same button or keeps sending the request because he doesn't know that thread is running on background for update.

I have some scenario at there and i want to know which approach i should follow to make a app very good performance wise:

#### Que.

If connection is slow and user clicks on a button and by the time i am sending the request to the server if user is online. So what should i do if he clicks on the another button (Sending the new request) or keep pressing the same button. I am running the same code for fetch the for both button. In my code if clicked it gets crashed or not working as i am expecting.
Solution in my mind :

- I can put the loading spinner and load the screen until it fully cached. But that is also not a good idea if the data is large or downloading the images from the server.
- Run the background thread check the status of the Asyntask whether background process is running or not(getStatus() checks whether the the AsyncTask is pending, running, or finished). If its running don't send the new update request.
- Single pattern.
- Services in Android

Is it a good approach to use the Executor on AsyncTask's (executeOnExecutor())

#### If you have any better suggestion for caching, you are welcome.

#### Thanks for considering...

Comment: Still waiting for an answer